# How to add 3D Tags in flutter UI?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I want to add 3d tags in my Flutter App UI like red tag in corner shown in reference image below.
Is there any package available for these?

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: I think you can do this by stack widget. If u can share this source code, I will can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Tooltip Widget [reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html)
and to customize refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62014287/4623392).

```
  Tooltip(
                verticalOffset:6.0,
                message: "${_getServiceList(position)}",
                textStyle: TextStyle(
          color: ColorConstants.whiteTwo,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          fontSize: 14),
                showDuration: Duration(seconds: 6),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: 1,
                    color: ColorConstants.pinkishGrey,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [
                    ColorConstants.toolTipRed,
                    ColorConstants.toolTipRed
                  ]),
                ),
                triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
                child: Icon(
                  size: 14,
                  Icons.info_outlined,
                  color: ColorConstants.appRed,
                ),
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

[3d tag image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBV62.png) I made custom 3d tag view you want just like that, Use this below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class ToolTipViewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const ToolTipViewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 300,
                  width: 320,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 35,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xffc9d6ea),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: 0,
                  top: 60,
                  child: Transform.translate(
                    offset: const Offset(16, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 37,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: const Color(0xfff2d6d3),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                                blurRadius: 7.0,
                                spreadRadius: 4,
                                offset: const Offset(
                                  5,
                                  5,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          child: const Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "TAT +80 D",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xffc94e40),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 2.0),
                          child: ClipPath(
                            clipper: TriangleClipper(),
                            child: Container(
                              color: const Color(0xffd7bfc9),
                              height: 10,
                              width: 22,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class TriangleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
      @override
      Path getClip(Size size) {
        final path = Path();
        path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
        path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
        path.close();
        return path;
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldReclip(TriangleClipper oldClipper) => false;
    }
```

Comment: No promoting your own products! By the way, explain how the code works cuz I can't otherwise I'd chosen to edit :D

Comment: @jett8998 I am not promoting my own product. As per the question asked above I have created this 3d tag view to help them.

Comment: @ jett8998  just navigate this screen and modify it as per you like

Comment: Oh sorry I was reviewing and too busy to take a look at ur image I thought it's a link to a repo or such